# How can I prevent a Windows 2003 local user account from being locked out?

Tags: windows-server-2003, security, user-accounts

I want to know if there's a way to prevent an account from every being locked out no matter how many times a password is entered incorrectly.  I know this is not a good security practice, but that is not the point of the question :)

Additionally, is there a way to change the number of failed attempts before the account is locked out.  Note, I only want to do this for one local user account, not all of them.

Thanks in advance for any advice you can give!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure this via Local Security Settings. AFAIK, this applies to all users and can't be applied to only one user. Also, if this computer is a member of a domain, these settings may be set via a domain GPO, which would over-ride the local setting.